# Flutter - Connectycube_flutter_callkit not working in the background or terminated

Tags: flutter, jitsi, jitsi-meet

i'm using connectycube for receiving calls but when i accept call while is in the background like the image below
[image: accept call not working]
it navigates me the home page but not the call here is the code

```
void videocaller( var friendName){
  Uuid uuid = Uuid();
  CallEvent callEvent = CallEvent(sessionId: uuid.v4() + "1", callType: 1, callerId: 0, 
  callerName: friendName, opponentsIds:{1234});

  Future<void> _onCallAccepted(CallEvent callEvent) async {
    _joinMeetingVideo(friendName);
   }

   Future<void> _onCallRejected(CallEvent callEvent) async {

   }
   Future onCallRejectedWhenTerminated(CallEvent? callEvent) async {

     }
   Future onCallAcceptedWhenTerminated(CallEvent? callEvent) async {
     _joinMeetingVideo(friendName);
   }

 ConnectycubeFlutterCallKit.onCallRejectedWhenTerminated = onCallRejectedWhenTerminated;
 ConnectycubeFlutterCallKit.onCallAcceptedWhenTerminated = onCallAcceptedWhenTerminated;
  ConnectycubeFlutterCallKit.instance.init(
    onCallAccepted: _onCallAccepted,
    onCallRejected: _onCallRejected,
  );
 ConnectycubeFlutterCallKit.showCallNotification(callEvent);
 ConnectycubeFlutterCallKit.setOnLockScreenVisibility(isVisible: true);

 }
```

i tried it with getx to navigate to jitsi call but it does not work

actually the problem is that jitsi function [_joinMeetingVideo(friendName);] is not a page where i can navigate to it's a function so it can't be executed enless the app is open this why it opens the home page of the app but not the video call itself but unfortunately i could't find a solution for this issue. any ideas ??

Comment: please provide the error or log after this "tried it with getx to navigate to jitsi call"? do you have a valid Context for navigation in your app after starting it by `onCallAcceptedWhenTerminated`?

Comment: are you sure that the function `onCallAcceptedWhenTerminated` satisfies the requirements of the plugin documentation?
```dart
  /// This provided handler must be a top-level function and cannot be
  /// anonymous otherwise an [ArgumentError] will be thrown.
```
looks like no, because it uses fields not related to the method arguments

Comment: are you sure that you have the right context in the function `_joinMeetingVideo(friendName);` for navigation to the next screen? could you provide any logs with errors or other info that will help to localize your issue?

Comment: You were right _joinMeetingVideo(friendName) is not a top level function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_joinMeetingVideo() is not a top-level function
```